# Clearing wxPython frame on a button click

Tags: wxpython

Using wxPython 2.8 on Arch (works fine, but I don't think it should...) and wxPython 2.9 on Mac OS X, both Python 2.7. My code consists of switching between different screens depending on the current states. On each switch between a state (screen) I clear my main Sizer and call DestroyChildren() on my main frame, then I populate them with other components.

So essentially I think I have outside threads trying to change wx components in the main thread. I'm guessing this is not best practise in wxPython, so how would I be able to amend this?

Attaching event to a button

```
self.login_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.login_button_click)
```

The log in event does stuff and calls an update (the model state is changed here)

```
def login_button_click(self,event):

    ...
    # CHANGE THE self.model.current_state
    ...

    self.update(None)
```

The update clears the frame, checks state and calls a builder method

```
def update(self, o):
    self.box.Clear() #clear the main sizer
    self.frame.DestroyChildren() #delete all children, THIS IS WHERE THE CODE SEGFAULTS


    print "STATE: "+self.model.current_state

    if self.model.current_state == self.model....
        ...
    elif self.model.current_state == self.model....
        ...
```

I have tried using wx.CallAfter, which resulted in all of the components beign removed at the end of the event, even the newly built ones.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using the threading module or anything related to threads? You really shouldn't need those to delete widgets in wxPython. I'm not sure why you're destroying all your widgets in the first place. Why not just hide the main frame and show a child frame with all the new widgets? Or use two panels. One panel is destroyed and a different panel with the other widgets is put in its place? I have an example of the latter on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/).

Comment: One weird thing I have happening is the frame.Layout() not working? As in to have the panels appear properly I need to resize the frame. I'm calling the Layout() method on the top level frame.

Comment: You may need to call Layout() on the sizer that contains the panels.

Comment: Tired a combinations of self.sizer.Layout() and self.Layout() with the same outcome. Does calling .Layout() force the re-Layout() of all the chidl elements btw? Or should I try calling Layout on the lower levels?

Comment: Normally you just call it on the top container and it lays out the children. If you can produce a simple runnable example, that would be great!